# What's the difference between Amazon EC2 private key (.pem) and secret access key?

Tags: amazon-ec2, private-key

While signing up for Amazon EC2 and enabling ssh, I have to create and download a private key (.pem) and a secret access key.

How are they different? What different functions do they have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read a good tutorial on SSH, but here is a summary:

The Access Key ID and Secret Access Key are like a username and password. They allow you to "do stuff" on the AWS API using the commandline tools or code you write.

The private key (.pem) is like a password for talking (SSH) to an individual box that you have launched. (i.e. not "AWS itself", but "your box within AWS".) You can have different passwords to different boxes if you want, but most of the time you only need one.

If you know how SSH works, they are just putting down ~/.ssh/known_hosts with the public part of your key, allowing you to log in for the first time. You can change that file later to add more users or rotate your SSH keys.

Comment: Hm, not sure the .pem is for SSH, I suspect it is the decrypt key used for Windows Instances (admin password)